# in_category() not working in WordPress 4.9.7

Tags: categories

I have the following code in a template that used to work until I upgraded to Wordpress 4.9.7

```
if (in_category( 'vid' )) {
    $vidliclass = ' class="vid"';
} else {
    $vidliclass = '';
}
```

Since the upgrade, posts that are in category vid don't return true anymore.

I used the following code, to check on the category names of the posts:

```
$postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
if ( ! empty( $postcat ) ) {
    echo esc_html( $postcat[0]->name );   
}
```

And the posts that are in category "vid" are echoed as vid.

I also tried to replace "vid" with the category ID.

Can I replace `in_category()` with something else to check if the post is in category "vid"?

Comment: in which template do you use this template tag? are you using it inside of the loop?

Comment: What context are you using it in? Are you inside [the loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/)? In your second bit of code, where is `$post` coming from? Also, which version did you update *from*? 4.9.6 or something earlier?

Comment: I updated from WordPress 4.9.1

Comment: I am using the code while looping through a get_posts query. $index_query = get_posts( array(
    'include'    => $index_query_filled,
 'orderby'=>'rand',
) );

foreach ( $index_query as $post ) : 
            setup_postdata( $post );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `in_category()` outside of a loop, so you need to pass the post ID in as the 2nd argument.

eg, `if (in_category( 'vid', $post->ID )) {`

See [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/).